# parsing html page in java without using external library

Tags: java

I know its an old question and have been asked many a times. Note :I cannot use external libraries. 
Given a function with label as argument, my function should return list of all the tags that contain that label.

I thought of saving my html as tree and then I can find the label and return list of all the tags. But I am not able to code it in java. How to completely parse and store html as tree structure and search on it?

Please help.

Thanks

Ravi

Comment: Lots of parsers are open source. You should take a look at how they do it.

Comment: Class assignment, or work task? If it's a work task, there's almost certainly a library that is under a business-friendly license. If it's a class assignment, can you provide some of the specs, particularly on what sort of html can be expected? Real html in the wild is much harder to parse than sample html for class assignments.

Comment: Actually, I was asked in an interview at a startup and I have been struggling to find a clear path to do it. I was just told : Given a html page, return list of all tags that contain that label.

Comment: Maybe you can use regex to solve this problem.

Comment: I am not very much in favour of regex and read most on stackoverflow and kind of convinced not to use regex. I was thinking of using HTMLDocument but I am not able to do with that too. Any suggestions or any code piece?

Comment: I have managed to get a tree structure for the html with some regex sine I am dealing with very well formatted html. Now as the question says, find all the tags that contain a particular label, given as argument to the function. I was thinking of using Preorder traversal but not the perfect approach I have in my head. Any suggestions, best possible way with minimum time and space complexity?